# sbt-assembly is not including scala libraries

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

The code I'm writing will be run in AWS Lambda which only has the Java 8 runtime installed so I need the scala libraries to be included in my jar. When I give it the jar I built with sbt-assembly I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function3`.

This is all I have in `build.sbt` for the assembly plugin:

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = true)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _                            => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

This still happens whether or not I have the line that discards the META-INF files.

I used brew to install scala and I have tried setting my $SCALA_HOME to `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea` (caveats section of `brew info scala`) and `/usr/local/bin/scala` (output of `which scala`)

:: EDIT ::

I unpacked the jar and found that the class in question was actually included in the jar here: `scala/Function3_scala-library-2.12.7_scala-library-2.12.7_scala-library-2.12.7.class`

Comment: does it only fail in AWS or also does in your local machine?, BTW, have you tried without using the `includeScala` _option_? - **that is the default behaviour**, I never set it and scala is always included, maybe there is a bug if you set it.

Answer (score 0):

I added `scala-library.jar` to my classpath in Intellij, removed the target folder and ran `sbt assembly` and that worked.